# Getting ERROR bad Request-Line

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a Canvas Facebook App which has a developer version(for test & dev purpose) accessed through localhost and a staging version deployed to Heroku. Whenever I try to access the developer version through localhost, I get the following error:

```
[2013-02-24 17:43:40] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00│\x01\x00\x00»\x03
\x02Q*Ñ¼X\x0EÑ÷╫┤EΩa▀f⌠├÷RNu#N╕╨6$╙iRZ╛\x00\x00H└'.
[2013-02-24 17:43:40] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00│\x01\x00\x00»\x03
\x02Q*Ñ¼π'k1w3Ää¿\x10ëσÅú├\x18$Æë{«ÄNù▐\x03$D\x00\x00H└'.
[2013-02-24 17:43:40] ERROR bad URI `!]è"!┼I\x00\x00H└'.
[2013-02-24 17:43:40] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00U\x01\x00\x00Q\x03
\x00Q*Ñ¼╦▐σ\x12╥N\x7Fi+∩£\x1Dcúë[1/°╡½ñV é₧·Y\x00\x00*\x00 \x00ê\x00ç\x009\x008\
x00ä\x005\x00E\x00D\x00f\x003\x002\x00û\x00A\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00/\x00\x16\x00\x1
3■ \x00'.
```

I have no problem accessing the staging version in heroku. To make things more interesting, my co developer does not have this problem when he tries to access the app through localhost. We are using the same environment(Windows OS and webrick server). I am suspecting  the problem is with my account, but I have no idea how to verify/fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing clearing the cache.
I was getting the same error while accessing api using **https** having **config.force_ssl = true**, but its working fine with **http** request.